# yocto custom image apply defconfig changes to kernel build

Tags: linux, embedded-linux, yocto, bitbake

I'm trying to apply some changes to the kernel configuration to my kernel image and to the device tree. In my custom layer my tree looks like this

```
meta-custom/
├── COPYING.MIT
├── README
├── classes
│   └── postprocess_image.bbclass
├── conf
│   └── layer.conf
├── recipes-core
│   └── images
│       └── custom-image.bb
├── recipes-example
│   └── example
│       └── example_0.1.bb
└── recipes-kernel
    └── linux
        ├── linux-qoriq
        │   └── ls1046ardb
        │       ├── 0001-usb0-devicetree-dtsi.patch
        │       └── fragment.cfg
        └── linux-qoriq_5.15.bbappend
```

and thats the content of my linux-qoriq_.bbappend file:

```
SRC_URI += "file://fragment.cfg"
SRC_URI += "file://0001-usb0-devicetree-dtsi.patch"
FILESEXTRAPATHS:prepend := "${THISDIR}/${PN}:"
PACKAGE_ARCH = "${MACHINE_ARCH}"
```

When I'm running `bitbake custom-image` during the build process .patch file and the .cfg file are copied to the folder where the linux kernel sources reside (`build_ls1046ardb/tmp/work/ls1046ardb-fsl-linux/linux-qoriq`) the devicetree patch get's applied correctly to the .dtsi file (`build_ls1046ardb/tmp/work/ls1046ardb-fsl-linux/linux-qoriq/5.15.32+gitAUTOINC+fa6c316859-r0/git/arch/arm64/boot/dts/freescale/fsl-ls1046a.dtsi`) and everything works as expected. But .cfg file changes are not applied to the `build_ls1046ardb/tmp/work/ls1046ardb-fsl-linux/linux-qoriq/defconfig` file and also not to the `build_ls1046ardb/tmp/work/ls1046ardb-fsl-linux/linux-qoriq/build/.conf` file which is used during to kernel build. I also tried to add the modified defconfig file directly to the linux-qoriq_5.15.bbappend file like this:

```
SRC_URI += "file://defconfig"
SRC_URI += "file://0001-usb0-devicetree-dtsi.patch"
FILESEXTRAPATHS:prepend := "${THISDIR}/${PN}:"
PACKAGE_ARCH = "${MACHINE_ARCH}"
```

But using this approach my defconfig file is not getting copied to `build_ls1046ardb/tmp/work/ls1046ardb-fsl-linux/linux-qoriq/defconfig` respectively overwrites the defconfig file that resides in the `build_ls1046ardb/tmp/work/ls1046ardb-fsl-linux/linux-qoriq/` folder. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

As described in this post https://community.nxp.com/t5/P-Series/qoriq-Linux-append-the-changes-in-kernel-configuration-not/m-p...  I appended DELTA_KERNEL_DEFCONFIG += "fragment.cfg" to my linux-qoriq_5.15.bbappend file and it looks like this now:

```
SRC_URI += "file://fragment.cfg"
SRC_URI += "file://0001-usb0-devicetree-dtsi.patch"
FILESEXTRAPATHS:prepend := "${THISDIR}/${PN}:
DELTA_KERNEL_DEFCONFIG += "fragment.cfg"
PACKAGE_ARCH = "${MACHINE_ARCH}"
```